# python boolean expression not "short-circuit"?

Tags: python, short-circuiting

For example:

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
    return 1
if any([f() for f in [foo]*3]):
   print 'bar'
```

I thought the above code should output:

```
foo
bar
```

instead of :

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
```

Why ? how can I make the "short-circuit" effect ?

Comment: Short answer: The `[f() for f in [foo]*3]` list comprehension executes and creates a list of `f()` return values **before** `any()` has a chance to evaluate them (and short-circuit).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Deconstruct your program to see what is happening:

```
>>> [f() for f in [foo]*3]
foo
foo
foo
[1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

You are already creating a list and passing to any and have printed it 3 times.

```
>>> any ([1, 1, 1])
True
```

This is fed to if statement:

```
>>> if any([1, 1, 1]):
...     print 'bar'
... 
bar
>>>
```

Solution: Pass a generator to any

```
>>> (f() for f in [foo]*3)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10041a9b0>
```

Comment: Great for python! what could be simpler than that !

Answer (score 5):

It's creating the list before passing it to any

try

```
def foo():
    print 'foo'
    return 1
if any(f() for f in [foo]*3):
   print 'bar'
```

this way only a generator expression is created, so only as many terms as necessary are evaluated.